# Wrong diacritic when using \"u

Tags: accents, characters, font-encodings

I have a document where the `\"u` is not rendered as ü, but more like a u with a strikethrough mark:

[image: Example of wrong diacritic]

Directly using the UTF-8 encoded ü character in the input file works as expected, however. I have the following classes/packages loaded (all with their default options, in this order):

- `letter`
- `ifthen`
- `graphicx`
- `lastpage`
- `fontenc`
- `ragged2e`
- `ngerman`
- `hyperref`

Anybody knows what could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I've tried and failed ;-) The problem cropped up when creating a new letter class. Just putting equivalent commands in a normal `.tex` file didn't exhibit the same problem.

Comment: well only few have crystal balls available, so I guess you need to try to get to an MWE.

Comment: Isn't that a small umlaut on a big letter rather than a strikethrough? I think you will need to show what fonts you are using, and how you loaded them. Start with the document that does that and remove packages one at a time until you can remove nothing more, then edit your question to add the MWE

Comment: Try if the problem goes away if you use `babel` with the option `ngerman` instead of the package `ngerman`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks, but that didn't help. I hoped that others have encountered this very problem, and the solution would be simple *sigh*... So I'll try to work out a MWE.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I stripped it down to a case showing the behaviour. You can find the class and test source here: https://gist.github.com/3011745

Comment: The output looks like the output of `\accent127 u` (when using a T1 encoded font). I could reproduce your output by forcing the use of an T1-encoded font while OT1-encoding is active. So check if your code use some font primitives like `\font` or `\newfont`, or if does some encoding switches. Edit: My crystalball seems to be in good shape. Your code uses `\newfont{\xiiiv}{phvr8t at 8.5pt}`. That's not a good idea!

Comment: Arrgh, that is some code I inherited from the previous maintainer. So something must have broken there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tricky problem. The issue is the following:

In your class file you define a number of  "fixed fonts".

```
\DeclareFixedFont{\x}{T1}{phv}{m}{n}{10}
\DeclareFixedFont{\xb}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{10}
\newfont{\xiiiv}{phvr8t at 8.5pt}
\newfont{\xiiivb}{phvb8t at 8.5pt}
```

But this is wrong in several respects.

- `\newfont` is not a LaTeX interface since 1994 (LaTeX2e) it is really only there for compatibility with 2.09 documents it should be `\DeclareFixedFont` throughout
- However, `\DeclareFixedFont`is not meant to load fonts for general typesetting. It gives you a font, right, but it doesn't set up the machinery to get all the special symbols autmatically choose the right slots. All that needs to be done by yourself in that case.

`\DeclareFixedFont` means that you load a font in a particular encoding in a particular size, but LaTeX afterwards doesn't know anything about this font. So all the hard work that automatically makes `\"u` select the right glyph or produce and accent on top of some glyph, etc. is not available.

Thus what happens is that LaTeX thinks it is typesetting in OT1 encoding (which means `\"u` produces an accent on top of `u`) while in reality the `\closing` command called `\x` (a T1 font). So it picks up the umlaut from the OT1 position (but in T1 there is this bar in this slot) and happily positions this on top of `u`.

So bottom line, forget about `\DeclareFixedFont`if you want to typeset general text and you don't know what diacritics come along and instead use the somewhat slower

```
\fontsize{10}{12}\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}
```

but then you have all diacritics set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that very thorough explanation. I actually tried not to meddle with the font code of the previous author of the class, but it seems I'll have to. I will give it a try immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I now rewrote everything in terms of `\fontsize` and `\usefont` using `\(re)newcommand`, and it seems to work perfectly. Provided I understood the font naming conventions correctly, I now also have the correct fonts following the corporate design...

Comment: Nearly nine years later, editing some ancient files and this has ended my search and trials - I needed this exact conversation. Thank you Frank and Michael!!